# sql row difference without cursor

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get date gap(in days) between rows. 
For example my data is ordered by saleDate and looks like the bellow:

```
ID  | saleDate                    ID  | gapInDays
10  | 1/1/2014                    10  | 4             -- (5/1/2014 -  1/1/2014).Days
20  | 5/1/2014                    20  | 2  
30  | 7/1/2014      ====>>>       30  | 3
40  | 10/1/2014                   40  | 7
50  | 17/1/2014                   50  | 1             --  last row will always be 1
```

doing it in code is not a big deal but because the amount of row is huge (few millions) I'm trying to do so in SP level. I assume I can use cursor but i understood it is very slow.

Any solution will be highly appreciated.

Pini.

Comment: Which DBMS you are using? SQL-SERVER/MY SQL/...?

Comment: On dev machine I'm using MS SQL 2008 R2 but I can always get the latest. The product runs in Azure cloud and uses Azure SQL. Currently Azure SQL doesn't support windows functions like lead/lag.... any thoughts?

Comment: @UshaP I updated my answer with a version that should work on Azure.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL SERVER 2012/Oracle/Postgres/DB2, then you have LEAD(), LAG() Functions.

```
select ID,saleDate,LEAD(saleDate) over (order by saleDate) DateOfNextRow
    ,Isnull(Datediff(dd,saleDate,LEAD(saleDate) over (order by saleDate)),1) as gapInDays
from Order
```

For SQL SERVER 2005/2008, you can use Window Functions like `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: Oracle, Postgres and DB2 also have `lead()` and `lag()`

Comment: Yep, I was sure about Oracle. Thanks, I have updated my answer.

Comment: AK47, Any thoughts about performance impact while using the suggested above?

Comment: We can always discuss on all Window functions & might come to customized answers as per situation. For nor take a look at this https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-performance-of-the-t-sql-window-functions/

Answer (score 1):

<del>If you are using MS SQL Server 2012 (or another database that supports the same, or similar functions) you can use the LAG() function to access previous rows (or LEAD() to access subsequent rows)</del>

Apparently you want this to work on SQL Azure that lacks the`LAG`and`LEAD`windowing functions.

One solution that should work is to use the`ROW_NUMBER`ranking function applied over the date column. Azure supports the`ROW_NUMBER`so this code should work:

```
select t1.id, isnull(datediff(day, t1.saledate, t2.saledate), 1) as gapInDays 
from 
(select id, saledate, rn = row_number() over (order by saledate, id) from gaps) t1
left join 
(select id, saledate, rn = row_number() over (order by saledate, id) from gaps) t2
on t1.rn = t2.rn-1
```

If you want it slightly more compact (and if Azure supports ctes which I believe it does) you can do it as a common table expression:

```
;with c as (
    select id, saledate, r = row_number() over (order by saledate, id) from gaps
)

select c.id, isnull(datediff(day, c.saledate, c2.saledate), 1) as gapInDays 
from c left join c c2 on c.r = c2.rn-1
```

In these queries I ordered the rows by saledate, if that is incorrect you might have to change it to `order by id, saledate` instead if it is the id that determines order.

Comment: Can you please explain me, what is difference between this & my answer?

Comment: I was just curios about you answer, To me also both ans were looking almost same, but I thought as you used LAG() there might be some benefits of using it over LEAD(). So I asked you.

Answer (score 0):

If your ids are strictly sequential you could do something like this

```
select 
    a.id, b.saleDate - a.saleDate 
from 
    yourTable as a, yourTable as b 
where 
    a.id = b.id-1
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style should **no longer be used** and instead it is recommended to use the **proper ANSI JOIN** syntax introduced with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 0):

If the database is SQL Server then following query should work.

```
WITH Sales AS
(
    SELECT
        *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SaleDate) AS RowNumber
    FROM
        TableName
)
SELECT
    DATEDIFF(DAY, T1.SaleDate, T2.SaleDate)
FROM
    Sales AS T1 INNER JOIN Sales AS T2
    ON  T1.RowNumber = T2.RowNumber - 1;
```